# Fonts supporting cursive cyrillic chars

Tags: fonts, cyrillic

I'd like to know if there is some font to produce the cursive Cyrillic characters as in the image

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This may partially explain the lack of easy to find fonts supporting cursive Cyrillic characters:

> The early Cyrillic alphabet is difficult to represent on computers. Many of the letterforms differed from modern Cyrillic, varied a great deal in *[manuscripts](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manuscript)*, and changed over time. Few fonts include adequate *[glyphs](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph)* to reproduce the alphabet. In accordance with *[Unicode](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)* policy, the standard does not include letterform variations or *[ligatures](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligature_%28typography%29)* found in manuscript sources unless they can be shown to conform to the Unicode definition of a character.
>
> The Unicode 5.1 standard, released on 4 April 2008, greatly improves computer support for the early Cyrillic and the modern *[Church Slavonic](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_Slavonic)* language. In Microsoft Windows, Segoe UI is notable for having complete support for the archaic Cyrillic letters since Windows 8.

**Source:** *[en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script)*